# Task List - start and then waitall

Tags: c#, .net, task

I want to do with List what the first method does with array.

The situation is don't know how many Tasks up front. I don't want to fill up a List before starting the task as it takes a while to fill up the list.

```
public void TaskArray()
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> cb = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    Task[] taskArray = new Task[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((Object obj) => {

            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1} on thread #{2}.",
                                i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        },
                                                i);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
}
```

This has syntax errors. 
Cannot convert from system.generic.task.list to system.threading.task.task

```
public void TaskList()
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> cb = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    List<Task> taskArray = new List<Task>;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        taskArray.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((Object obj) => {
            cb.Add(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Task #{0} created at {1} on thread #{2}.",
                                i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        },
                                                i));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `taskArray.ToArray()`?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Got rid of the syntax error but it give me the wrong answer.  If you want to post that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Downvote and VTC a question with an accepted answer.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  I got an answer so I am happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `taskArray` is a `List<Task>` you may just use:

```
Task.WaitAll(taskArray.ToArray());
```